# SQL Parameter that checks filters records returned within the entire last 3, 6, 9 months or year

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2014

I am trying to write a stored procedure that only returns data for the past 3, 6, 9 months or year.  It needs to be full months only (if pulling 8/15; most recent would be July)

So far I have been able to find out how to find out the 1st and last day of the previous month.

```
SELECT DATEADD(m,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()), 0))as 'First day of the month',
DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)) as 'Last day of the month'
```

The field that will need to be checked for is TransactionDateKey (ie 20161222).  I think I should use a CAST on that field to only check for the month and day (ie 201612) but I could be wrong.  Below is a rough mock-up of what I think I should be basing my query on but without the hard-coded dates

```
select FirstName + ' ' + LastName as 'Specialist',
    empID as 'empID',
    count(fact.spKey) as 'Count',
    CAST(LEFT(CAST(TransactionDateKey AS VARCHAR(100)), 6) AS INT) as 'Month'
from Final.DimSpecialist s
    inner join Final.FactTreatmentDay fact
        on fact.spKey = s.spKey
where TransactionDateKey between 20161201 and 20161231
group by FirstName + ' ' + LastName,
    empID,
    CAST(LEFT(CAST(TransactionDateKey AS VARCHAR(100)), 6) AS INT)
```

How would I go about declaring a single parameter, @MonthRange, and using it in the WHERE clause to only return data for the past 3 months, 6 months, 9 months or a year? I think the parameter will need to be placed where -1 is in 'First day of the month'.  I think there should also be a case statement to check for the each of the 4 possible parameter values, but I am not sure where it should go.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are some interesting ways to date calculations using a date dimension table where you have a yearmo field, I have chosen to provide an answer that closely matches what you already have an is applicable if you don't have such a table :-)

```
declare @months_to_report int;  --procedure parameter

--Validation
if @months_to_report not in (3, 6, 9, 12) raiserror('Months to report must be one of 3, 6, 9, or 12.', 18, 1);

--Variables
declare @first date, @start date, @end date, @start_key int, @end_key int;

set @first = DATEADD(m,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()), 0));     --first day of previous month
set @end = DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0));        --last day of previous month
set @start = DATEADD(M, 1 - @months_to_report, @first);                 --move back n-1 months to account for including previous month

set @start_key = Year(@start) * 10000 + Month(@start) * 100 + Day(@start);  --start date as keys
set @end_key = Year(@end) * 10000 + Month(@end) * 100 + Day(@end);  --end date as keys

select @first as 'First day of the month', @start as 'First day of reporting period', @end as 'Last day of the month/reporting period', @start_key as 'Start key', @end_key as 'End key';
```

This code assumes that the parameter being passed is `@months_to_report`. I prefer to validate parameters in stored procedures. The end `select` is only for debug purposes. You would modify your provided example code to follow this and supplement @start_key and @end_key for your hard-coded dates.